# Пытаюсь внедрять сценарии Ruby в spring

Tags: java, spring, ruby

***Пытаюсь внедрять сценарии Ruby в spring из книги springinaction,бросает исключение в xml файле, наверное как-то не так сделал расположение файлов или еще что, может кто помочь?***

- resources/scripting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="coconut" class="app.scripting.Coconut" p:lime-ref="lime"/>

    <lang:jruby id="lime" script-source="classpath:app/scripting/Lime.rb"
<!-- Здесь ошибка -->                    script-interfaces="app.scripting.Lime"/>

</beans>
```

- App.java

```
package app;

import app.scripting.Coconut;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"/event.xml", "/scripting.xml"});
        Coconut coconut = (Coconut) ctx.getBean("coconut");
        coconut.drinkThemBothUp();

    }
}
```

- Lime.rb

```
    require 'java'

    class Lime
      def drink
        puts "Callled the doctor woke him up!"
      end
    end
```

- мое дерево проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- мой стек

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=3683:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\Work\Spring\spring-in-action\events\events\target\classes;C:\Users\vadim\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vadim\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vadim\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vadim\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vadim\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\vadim\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar app.App
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 17 in XML document from class path resource [scripting.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 43; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'lang:jruby'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:95)
    at app.App.main(App.java:12)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 43; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'lang:jruby'.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:511)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3587)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2143)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:849)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2710)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 14 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'lang:jruby'

Как я понимаю вот основной косяк

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключил ***sdk*** ***ruby*** + ***compiler***. и сработало!